# SQL UPDATE: Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having trouble with this update statement. I'm not sure how to re-phrase it so that for each item in my "in" statement, it updates the rule ID to 109.

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET RuleID = 109 
WHERE mytable.ItemId in (534157, 534154);
```

This fails and gives me the following error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure CLID_Hist, Line 17
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
>   The statement has been terminated.

I'd appreciate someone's help. For a given list of ItemID's, I want to update the RuleID to 109.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the `CLID_Hist` procedure? Is there a trigger on this table that runs for each update? This statement here on its own should not cause any trouble ...

Comment: Exactly, this query should work. Are you trying to execute more than this query?

Comment: Agree with above posters, this SQL as you currently have it in your question should work fine.  Check the table in question for triggers.

Comment: I'll look for a trigger on the table. I'm not trying to excute more then this at this time.

Comment: Something's up. If I change the "in" to an "=", and do them one at a time, the update runs. But I cannot do them as an "in."

Comment: The problem is really inside that procedure... you'll have to modify it in order to do a batch update.

Comment: Thanks @marc_s! I had a similar problem, and it was a trigger. I didn't even notice that part of the error message.

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
UPDATE mytable SET RuleID = 109 WHERE ItemId IN (534157, 534154);
```

You don't need the `FROM` clause since you're working with the same table.

Here's the SQL Fiddle to play with the data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/238dd/2

It's working just fine.

Comment: Thanks. I removed the random from clause  I had in my orginal post and I'm getting the same error when I use your update statement.

Answer (score 1):

just get rid of the "from" clause line, if that is literally the query you are using.